# RESTApi endpoint for google home for accessing google NestHub gen2 notification

Tags: rest, google-api, notifications, calendar, google-home

So i want to integrate my google calendar to my google nest hub gen 2 . Google home app has a feature to notify user with message at a specific time daily but you have to set it up manually.Now i want to integrate that notification with google calendar so it will create dynamic notification.

Looked for some restAPI endpoint but not found any ? Can anyone help me with it .

Answer (score 0):

At this moment there is no option to directly link Google Calendar events to notifications on Nest Hub via API. There are some workarounds but as you mentioned you have to set these up manually.

You can use [Google Assistant Routines](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7029585?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) to create automated reminders with custom messages triggered by event times. The Routine would include:

- A voice command trigger (optional, e.g., "Hey Google, remind me about [event name]").
- A scheduled time trigger based on the event's start time in your Google Calendar.
- An action to display a custom message on your Nest Hub screen.

You can also set up [Personal Results](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7684543?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) in the Google Home app to see your upcoming events on the Nest Hub screen. While the Nest Hub won't show a full calendar view, it can display the next two upcoming events.